(geometry nodes) Is there a way to create a crossable decal system?
The idea is to create a decal system with intersections (crossing).
The problem is the overlapping profiles.

This is my approach, you draw a curve on a surface (intersection would be nice but for the sake of simplicity, the overlaps would only have to be at nodes).

Then you would have to outline the curve. The large distance is only for better clarity.

This is what it would look like with a curve profile.
This is what it should look like, just with adjusted corners.

The texture could be implemented either with normal maps or with bump maps (looks a bit washed out and could be better).

I’m just a geometry nodes beginner and it’s often beyond my horizon :).
Maybe these implementation ideas can help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvCPQXQy-OY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSkCTGc0ZTc

Could you edit your post to include a question?

I have to agree with @DannyBeckett, here, please open with a simple statement of one  problem..  what you want, what you've got, what the difference is, and what you've tried.
